# Does jQuery .dialog() have a default width?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

If I don't specify the width parameter for a jQuery modal dialog, what width will the dialog window have when opened?

```
$(foo).dialog('open')
```

Is it 300?

Where is it specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [`jquery-ui.css`](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) CSS file, line `228`.

If you'd like to override it, just add this chunk of code to your own CSS file and it should work:

```
.ui-dialog {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width

It defaults to 300. Change it like so:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ width: 460 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default width is 300. You can see that in the [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-width):

> width Number Default:300

In the [jQuery UI source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L71), you can see that the `width` option defaults to 300:

```
options: {
    width: 300
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default is indeed 300.

[JQueryUI - Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Click the 'options' tab and then scroll down to the width section.  The default is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Default width for jQuery UI Dialog is 300

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    width: auto;
}
```